# Python: how to get all the ordered combinations of set of lists

Tags: python, iteration

let say I have the following lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [11, 12, 13]
c = [111, 112, 113]
```

I want to have the following output

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,13]
[1,2,113]
[1,12,3]
[1, 12, 13]
[1, 12, 113]
[1,112,3]
[1,112,13]
[1, 112, 113]
[11,2,3]
[11, 2, 13]
[11, 2, 113]
[11, 12, 3]
[11, 12, 13]
[11, 12, 113]
[11, 112, 3]
[11, 112, 13]
[11, 112, 113]
...
```

Hence, I want to have a function that will give me all the listing combinations,  which are selections of some members of a set where order is disregarded - a set of lists when each element in them keep his index from the original list.

I went over all the options in `itertools` and didn't find any solution.

Comment: I would like to add the following to other answers: What you want to do is not listing all permutations since permutations are the act of (re)arranging all the members of a set, if you want to list all permutations stuff will change order because different positions means different permutation, what you want to do is listing combinations, which are selections of some members of a set where order is disregarded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `zip` your lists before using `product`:

```
from itertools import product

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [11, 12, 13]
c = [111, 112, 113]

for p in product(*(zip(a, b, c))):
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 13)
(1, 2, 113)
(1, 12, 3)
(1, 12, 13)
(1, 12, 113)
(1, 112, 3)
(1, 112, 13)
(1, 112, 113)
(11, 2, 3)
(11, 2, 13)
(11, 2, 113)
(11, 12, 3)
....
```

To answer your comment: the output of `zip`is:

```
print(list(zip(a, b, c)))
#  [(1, 11, 111), (2, 12, 112), (3, 13, 113)]
```

Then `product` will generate its output by taking one value in each of these 3 tuples.

Answer (score 0):

```
 a = [1, 2, 3]
 b = [11, 12, 13]
 c = [111, 112, 113]
 d=[]
 for i in range(3):
     d.append((a[i],b[i],c[i]))
 print(d)
 for i in range(len(d)):
     for k in range(3):
         for j in range(3):
             print(d[0][i],d[1][k],d[2][j])
```

This will help i guess